# Is there an example of Egypt recording defeat?

Tags: bible, egypt

Some defenders of the Torah's historical accuracy respond to a lack of evidence for the exodus from Egypt with **the claim that Egypt simply didn't make records of its negative events**. For example, Rabbi Dovid Gottlieb from [Ohr Somayach](http://ohr.edu/) (a [yeshiva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshiva)) [says](http://ohr.edu/2053): (emphasis is theirs)

> Why is it that no ancient Egyptian records mention the Exodus? The answer is that the Egyptians *never* recorded their defeats.

Is this claim true? **Can anyone cite an example of the Ancient (let's say from the era of 2000-500 BCE)? recording defeat suffered in battle?** Are the only records of Egyptian losss from non-Egyptian records ?

Comment: Is that relevant? Even if the Egyptians never recorded their defeat, the common working hypothesis is that if the exodus occurred, there would be ample evidence of the Jewish people *living* in Egypt. There is no such evidence. It’s not only the exodus that doesn’t have any evidence, it’s the whole deal.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think relevancy is a matter of personal taste. Here there seems to be a notable claim ("Egyptians never recorded their defeats.") that has only a thin connection with the Old Testament and with the Jewish people in general.

Comment: @belisarius My second question was pondering ahead, like if they do record defeats but there's also missing records of some victories, a revised claim could be made like "Their records are simply incomplete." But I suppose that's diverging from the main claim to test so I'll remove it from my question.

Comment: @belisarius That’s certainly true. But the implication is that this has a bearing on the truthiness of (this particular passage in) the Bible, and I see that as a straw man.

Comment: you can't prove a negative like this, it's simply impossible. What if they made records but those were later lost or destroyed? Impossible to prove one way or the other. So at most you'll be able to show that you could not find any such records, which is not the same as it could well mean that either your research was incomplete or none have ever been found yet because of incomplete research by others.

Comment: Strictly, the OP's question is asking to disprove a negative, not to prove it; so, even one example of an Egyptian record of defeat would disprove the claim that "Egytians *never* recorded their defeats". I think that's enough to qualify it for this site (that and the referenced, specific, notable (AFAIK) claim), although IMNSHO I think it's a mediocre question. I think this question (about commonly/secularly accepted historical study of Ancient Egypt) is a better fit on History.SE and not here.

Comment: Also, it seems that the 'skeptical core' of this (and OP's other recent question) is "Is Exodus historically accurate?" (Or maybe a larger biblical selection?) OTOH, I think if that's what OP wants to ask, he should ask it directly. OTOH, I think it's a sub-par question: fundamentalists will believe a literal reading regardless of the evidence, and most everyone else does *not* view it as a reliable historical document. I would think that 'practical skeptics' (ha ha) wouldn't waste time on this, but that it's a field day for unresolvable arguments. // @jwenting I forgot to tag prev comm to you

Comment: @hunter2 from OPs other questions here and at history.se I think he's less interested in historical data as in confirming his political/religious ideology.

Comment: @jwenting Yup, that's my suspicion, too.  But there are plenty of questions here on Skeptics that seem to me to be 'within the rules, but inadvisable'; so, if the OP wants to start a religious argument .. stop dancing around it. IMO, of course ...  (Stated alternately: he should either ask questions that fit SE (historical/factual/objectively answerable), or take his flamebait/ideology arguments to a more appropriate forum.)

Comment: @hunter2 Is yours a notable claim? May I ask here if "The previous OP's posts arise suspicion about their future ones" and don't be downvoted? :)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I understand your POV, but I don't like the idea of pre-judging _intentions_

Comment: @belisarius It’s hardly pre-judging, the intentions are *explicit* in the claim. That said, I’m not against investigating the claim per se at all. I *do* insist on the disclaimer (and, having commented, I’ve now satisfied that).

Comment: @belisarius, which claim? If someone were to ask "Is Exodus historically accurate?", then the claim is the contents of Exodus, and I think the claimant would either be the author (!) or the people who regard it as literal, historical truth; as I've indicated, I *think* that people who do so ('regard as literal') are a small minority and that there's not much point in arguing with them - but yes, it's a notable claim. I don't understand your second question ...

Comment: Whoa! This [site](http://www.gks.uk.com/egyptian-battles-smiting/) claims that the lack of available evidence for the battles described in Ancient Egyptian records is evidence of... umm... space-battles between planets and moons? (I think - The thesis isn't terribly clear.)

Comment: To settle the suspicions of @hunter2 and all: I'm not trying to start a religious debate nor confirm ideology nor looking for this site to aid me in a debate. I also don't care to ask whether Exodos is historically accurate. It is true that the subject matter is an interest of mine; otherwise I wouldn't ask. And as such, I do come across claims, and I want to find out if their specifics are true, one way or the other. Maybe this question would be a better fit for history.SE; I personally thought this site was a good resource for the character of the question.

Comment: OK, good to know I guess.  I still think this fits *better* on History.   On this one, I think your question is pretty clear, and it is (or is close enough to) phrased in a way that sounds like a Skeptic question, but ... +1 Tacroy's comment. // (The other one is, ATM, too unclear for me to even speculate.)

Comment: At that particular time, the Egyptians were THE powerhouse, and very hard to defeat in battle because of their superior technology and numbers.  That said, I seem to recall some writings about the Egyptians losing battles to "the sea people" in the 12th century BCE.  Just that alone would be a refutation of the "didn't record losses" argument...

Comment: @Brightblades Did they write they lost battles to the sea people or simply that the sea people were a known force that battled elsewhere?

Comment: Presumably, you are familiar with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Kadesh

Comment: @FelixGoldberg That is a battle where Egypt seems to say they won. It's possible it's propaganda where they did record the battle, and it was a defeat, but even that's not clear.

Comment: And what about the Hyksos?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg The Hyksos did take control. As they would have been the ones in power, records of them would be more victory than defeat.

Comment: @AL Unless the records we have are from later periods, where their rise and fall is described from the Egyptian point of view - that would be your example. But I'm afraid I'm out of my depth now - I know that Manetho mentioned them but he is too late a source to be relevant. I don't know if they were meniotned in early papyri.

Comment: I don't know if it's true, but I was always told there were records of payments to Jewish people. They were employed with fairly acceptable wages for that time to work as skilled workers at building sites. Masons, stone cutters etc. were payed in silver or grain for their services.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not sure what you mean by "Jewish" people because that term did not exist at the time. But there is evidence of Hebrew/Semitic people being in Egypt. In addition to the Egyptian history of Manetheo, there are references to the "Apiru" which many of suggested is the "Ivrim." And theres Brooklyn Papyrus which lists the names of slaves including many Hebrew/Semitic names found in the Torah (e.g. Shifrah, Menahem, Asher, etc.)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First and foremost, you've got to understand what it is that ancient historians mean by "records" of ancient Egypt. We do not, by and large, have accounting ledgers or encyclopedias from that time. They may have existed (well, probably not in the case of the latter) but they are gone to us. What we have instead are the objects that were left behind: sarcophagi, obelisks, the insides of the Pyramids themselves, and so on. For the same reason your local town probably doesn't have a statue on Main Street commemorating the time your country lost a war, these artifacts tend to be heavy on the wins and light on the losses.

There are also archaeological type artifacts such as the tools that were used during this time, the bodies of workers and the pharoahs, and so on, but those, too, tend not to come with instructions. As incredible as people are nowadays at extrapolating out nuggets of information from this evidence, stuff like "oh, in 3496 they lost a battle to the Assyrians" is just not going to appear in these records.

What we do have in the case of Egypt are long periods of time where there isn't a great deal of recorded history. For example, the [First Intermediate Period](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Intermediate_Period_of_Egypt) was a time when the lights went out, so to speak. There's still a decent amount of information to be had from the period but nowhere near like what we have before and after. We can surmise from the way the art differed that there was a bit of a split in the empire during this 100 year period, but beyond that, it seems that a lot of what we know about this period of time is what folks said about it afterwards.

Add to that the fact that we've only been able to read hieroglyphics for [about 180 years now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_stone) and you start to get an inkling as to what we have to use.

As to the specific claims made by the Bible and the Exodus, there is just plain no way that several hundred thousand Jews lived in the Nile delta. There's simply no evidence for a group of that size. Some Egyptologists (notably Robert Breyer) think that the legends may be based on a group that was actually there, but if so they were orders of magnitude smaller than what is portrayed in the Bible and might be better referred to as proto-Jewish rather than actual members of the established tribe.

Comment: No problem. It's all but impossible to prove a negative.

Comment: @AL There's nothing to disprove, the assumption that the Egyptians should have recorded their defeats is false. It's an anachronistic argument that doesn't take into account the propagandistic nature of Egyptian records. The argument also falsely assumes that records of defeat would stand the same changes as records of triumphs to survive to this day. Even if records of defeat existed, they wouldn't be found in the friezes in Karnak (for example); they would be written in fragile papyrus, that would have disintegrated after a century or two.

Comment: Well depends on what's meant by record. There might be secondary sources (just speculating on what's possible) like - I don't know - some priest ritual dispelling bad luck, offerings to apparently not so generous gods or some sort of payment record of soldiers, weapons commissions ...stuff like that. Historians don't specifically need a direct source stating "we lost" to know they lost, or otherwise.

Comment: @yannis I think that is exactly Rabbi Gottlieb's point. We would expect to see any discussion of the plagues in the Egyptian "records" we have today. Any writing about it, would have long disintegrated.

Answer (score 9):

There are a number of Egyptian defeats known to history - some of them come to us from contemporaneous accounts from neighboring civilizations, others from archaeological evidence, but many of them come from the Egyptian historical record.

In direct answer to your question, here is the [Victory Stela of Piye](http://realhistoryww.com/world_history/ancient/Victory_Stela_of_Piye.htm), which documents the conquests of the Nubian kingdom of Kush in Egypt and Libya. It details battles in which Egyptians lose, and badly, to Piye's Nubian army. Piye's image has been somewhat inexpertly redacted by subsequent Pharaohs, but the text remains untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion that Egypt did not record its military defeats and disasters is flatly wrong. The Egyptians were united not just ethnically and religiously, but their scholars were also able to record their defeats, break them down, counter the tactics which defeated them and the weaponry which was superior to their own. The Double-arched bow wasn't invented in Egypt, it was a Hyskos invention, similarly the chariot was integrated into the army as an invention of the Hurs.

You can read all about the times when they were beaten and how they got around to beating them back. The Kushite Nubians and the Canaanite Hyskos in particular gave the Egyptians a fair thumping in the Middle Kingdom, so much so that they were forced to sign peace treaties.

The Ipuwer Papyrus is the favourite document used by creationists and bible bashers because it describes in graphic detail a list of disasters which befell Egypt, including a period of darkness which may or may not have been literal, and the waters of the Nile turning blood red, stinking and being generally unfit for drinking. They do this at the same time that they ironically deny that Egypt recorded such disasters. What they wont tell, is that this was from a time well before the Jews were allegedly in Egypt.

So the claim that the Egyptians did not record their woes militarily or domestically, being an excuse for the thorough lack of any sort of corroborating documentation for the bible is flatly wrong.

Comment: This answer would be improved by sources.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.reshafim.org.il/ad/egypt/ramseskadeshcampaign.htm

The whole battle was a draw at best. It can even be argued the Egyptians lost. Still the Egyptians recorded the Hittite king crawling at Pharaoh’s feet. Asking the great and mighty son of god for mercy. The Hittite king offered Pharaoh his service and land in exchange for being spared.

With that in mind how do you think Egyptians would record being defeated by a bunch of (almost) unarmed slave men, women and children on foot?
I think the most plausible answers are:
●   Nothing was written down out of shame.
●   It was written down as another huge victory but the records are lost.

I'm not claiming the Egyptians never recorded any defeat, but I think the above clearly shows they sometimes were quite 'flexible' with the truth :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in America there are plenty of monuments to the Vietnam War, which was a huge humiliating defeat for the country. Now ancient Egypt might be different. It is plausible that the Egyptians would not have wanted to record their defeats, but bare in mind that this is not the only reason why some skeptics of the biblical narrative disbelieve the Jewish enslavement and exodus. Their disbelief isn't founded entirely on the fact that there are no Egyptian recordings of it - there is simply no historical or archaeological evidence for it *anywhere* outside the bible, not in Egypt or in Sinai, nowhere. And the story doesn't fit into the larger historical context of the kingdoms that existed at that time. In fact, in ~1400 BC, which is roughly when the exodus is supposed to have happened, Canaan was controlled by the Egyptian Kingdom.

Comment: Note though that the official government narrative is that they didn't loose Vietnam. Technically they reached a peace agreement all parties agreed on.

Comment: and those monuments don't commemorate the war, they remember the local dead of that war.

Answer (score -3):

To answer the question that the op asked because everyone was too biased to simply say it. No the Egyptians have not shown evidence of admitting defeat in their history that is currently looked at and known.

Comment: Any source for this claim?

Comment: Not much of an "answer", but on the other hand the OP is asking to prove the negative, so you can hardly blame someone for just saying "No."

Comment: @TylerDurden Except that some of the existing answers contradict this.